# Way to Consume Json request as Json object in Jersey Rest Service

Tags: json, rest, jersey

Hi I tried googling around but cannot find solution that I want to achieve.

Example to map json to java object we do

```
 @POST
 @Consumes(application/json)
 @Produces(application/json)
 public Response createUpdateDeleteManualClinicalData(MyJavaPojo definedPojo) {
   // this maps any json to a java object, but in my case I am dealing with generic json structure
}
```

What I want to achieve is Keep it as json object itself

```
public Response createUpdateDeleteManualClinicalData(JSONObject json)
```

Work around: I can get data as plain text and convert that to json. But its an overhead from my side which I want to avoid.

Edit: I am open to using any Json library like JsonNode etc... as far as I get Json object Structure  directly without the overhead of String to Json from my side. This should be common usage or am I missing some core concept here.

Comment: Why do you use JSONObject if you can give more detail, I can give more attractive solution. But my solution, you can use hashmap if you want a key value relation to json.

Comment: I am very interested to see your solution to convert payload to maps but I would also like to have json object directly which I can pass around to different sources in my infrastructure who wants to process the same request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a straight solution that I happened to overlooked... my bad.
Jersey is way smarter than I thought... curious to know what magic happens under the layers

```
@POST
 @Consumes(application/json)
 @Produces(application/json)
 public Response createUpdateDeleteManualClinicalData(JsonNode jsonNode) {
//jsoNode body casted automatically into JsonNode
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the web.xml configuration you are using? Is it something similar to here [web.xml setup gists for Jersey1 and Jackson2](https://gist.github.com/mallim/6462665)?

Comment: Yes. I am using the same stuff

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same configuration as [web.xml setup gists for Jersey1 and Jackson2](https://gist.github.com/6462665.git), then you may do as below. This is a possible alternative than using JSONObject

```
@POST
@Path("/sub_path2")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Map<String,Object> saveMethod( Map<String,Object> params  ) throws IOException {

    // Processing steps

    return params;
}
```